# Qt 4.8.5 QGraphicsView::fitInView fails to fit exactly

Tags: c++, qt

I Have a problem trying to fit my content (stretch) of a scene into my QDeclarativeView. I load a QML file the common way. I overrode the showEvent and resizeEvent method with the code below:

```
QGraphicsItem* rootItem = this->scene()->items.at(0);
QRectF rootRect = rootItem->sceneBoundingRect(); // it gives me a QRectF(0,0,1920,1080)
this->fitInView(rootRect, Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio); // Aspect doesn't matters.
```

The problem is that it keeps showing a little white border (almost 4 pixels) around the content. I've tested in 1920x1080, 1920x1200 and 1440x900 and all those resolutions on my desktop shows the content with the same problem. Even out of fullscreen mode it keeps the little white border.

Just to make sure it was nothing from the content, I have set the view's background brush to black and the white border became black (in other words, the content is being scaled down too much to fit in view).

Subtracting values from rectangle hardcoding is not an option once it's varying the background portion depending on the content size. (It should adapt dynamically).

Any suggestions?

Comment: If you're trying to fit the whole scene into the view with fitInView, what I think you're seeing is the borders of the mainWindow (QDeclarativeView). Look at removing those to prevent the white border displaying. It may be that setting the frameRectangle to a zeroed rect, or inheriting and setting the margins to zero will help.

Comment: @Merlin069 It's not the window frames. It's the scene background as I told on the question description. The palliative solution is to paint the scene background with a black QBrush (I'm using a dark background image on the QML file).

Comment: Just to mention, I've already tried the stylesheet property without success. It's not a border. The real problem is that fitInView is not exact fitting the content.

Comment: Sorry, I've previously come across a similar issue where, regardless of the scene colour, if the view was set to display the full scene a border was displayed, which turned out to be from the window hosting the view. I thought this might have been the same problem.

Comment: Have you solved this problem ? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried setting the item's pen to cosmetic and possibly also setting the pen's width to 0? Qt5 works differently than Qt4 in that aspect as far as rendering goes but I think that it is also calculated into the items shape rect.

Comment: Not solved yet. Rewrote the code on Qt 5.0. Trying to fix on the source code and push a solution to Qt dev team.

Comment: could you submit a bug report maybe, and leave the link here. I have just run into the same issue.

Comment: There is already a bug report for this (QTBUG-11945).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just encountered the problem as well. Since the bug is not about to be solved, I'll post my partial solution. I subclassed QGraphicsView and added a method myFitInView(), that does the required scaling and centering automatically.

I guess if you need more performance you could also directly fill the the matrix, but I don't need this and therefore scale and center seperately.

Also, any previous view transformations are lost with this approach, but you could probably account for that as well, by getting the current matrix and modifying/multiplying it accordingly.

```
void MyGraphicsView::myFitInView(QRectF const &rect)
{
  QRectF viewRect = frameRect();

  double scaleX = viewRect.width() / rect.width();
  double scaleY = viewRect.height() / rect.height();

  QTransform trans;
  trans.scale(scaleX, scaleY);
  setTransform(trans, false);

  centerOn(rect.width() / 2, rect.height() / 2);
}
```

Comment: Its an elegant solution. Although I would like to test it on the code I had 2 years ago, when I originally had this problem. The project was migrated to Qt 5.2 and it does not happen on this version. I am accepting it as a correct answer.

Comment: I'm on Qt 5.4.1 and encountered the exact problem.

Comment: It's not happening on 5.2.0 (we are not updating it anymore). You should try. Are you sure it is not a context problem? Are you using the new opengl scene graph?

Answer (score 1):

seems like a bug in Qt: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-11945.
my ugly workaround for that is

```
QRectF removeMargin11945(const QRectF& sceneRect, const QSize& viewerSize){
    const int bugMargin = 2;
    const double mx = sceneRect.width()/viewerSize.width()*bugMargin;
    const double my = sceneRect.height()/viewerSize.height()*bugMargin;
    return sceneRect.adjusted(mx, my, -mx, -my);
}
```

What makes it particularly ugly is that sometimes it is not required and things just work fine, be careful to distinguish those cases.

Comment: Not acceptable once the solution should work on multiple resolutions and aspect ratio. The margin is not constant. It depends on the resolution.